# how to get ethernet ip address on raspberry pi zero

Tags: pi-zero

I have ethernet hat board on my raspberry pi zero. But my zero could not obtain the ip address in my network. How can it be fixed?

Comment: `hostname -I` gives you that. Or look in your router's control panel and see what address has been assigned. Or use a tool like `nmap` or https://www.fing.com/ or https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/ to scan your network.

Comment: What operating system do you use? How do you check that it does not obtain an ip address?

Answer (score 1):

How the RPi Zero is connected through LAN, with the router or something else?
If with router, then please check whether DHCP configuration has been enabled or not in the router.

Enable th DHCP in you RPi Zero also.

Also, from terminal check the `ifconfig` command output. You are getting the node correctly or not.

Still, if it will not work, then try to assign the static IP, Gateway and Netmask to the RPi Zero and connect it with your PC/Laptop. Check local pinging.